# SQL - i want to save Request of customer and show match request when new product added

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

Sorry for my english.  i want to save Request of customer and  show  match request  when new product added .
this is my sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24ef1/2

Comment: You should indicate your programming language with a tag.

Comment: make sure that the sqlfiddle containing code

Comment: add the code of the request of customer and its relation with the product, this will help your question get answer faster